# Installing Dynamics 365 CE V9 in docker container

Tags: image, docker, installation, containers, dynamics-crm

I googled Dynamics 365 onprem docker and found that Microsoft has made Business Central onprem available as docker containers.
But I didnt find anything about Dynamics 365 CE.

I've seen that there is a Windows Server Core docker file, and that Dynamics supposedly is supposed to work with that verison (except SSRS reports).

Today we are using VM for local development and those take up alot of space and are quite slow on laptops.

Would be awesome if possible to run Dynamics 365 on docker instead.

My questions is:

- Have you ever managed to do this?
- Is it even possible? If so:
- Is there a guide?
- Do you know where I can find those images if any?

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: I couldn't find any